# How to pass an event parameter in addition to your own custom parameters in React when the custom parameter is getting data from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am programming in React and passing data between a parent(TodoForm.js) and child(PrioritySelector.js) component. In this case, I want to get data from child component so I passed my custom parameter to the function "handleSubmit", and I passed that function over to the child component as a prop(getData={this.handleSubmit}). Now, I am able to retrieve the data from the child component, however, when I want to pass an "e" parameter for e.preventDefault argument,it gives me an error. Such as TypeError: e is not a function. Does anyone know a way I can pass these two parameters(custom param and event param) in the same method? Thanks so much. My code is below. Thanks!

```
import React from "react";
import PrioritySelector from "./PrioritySelector";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class TodoForm extends React.Component {


    /*submit handler to grab input from the input references and store them
    in the "todoData" object. Then dispatches an action type and payload
    capturing the data. Then clears the input*/
    handleSubmit=( priorityLevelData, e)=> {
       e.preventDefault()
        const todoTitle = this.getTodoTitle.value;
        const description = this.getDescription.value;
        const priorityLevel = priorityLevelData;
        const todoData = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000),
            todoTitle,
            description,
            priorityLevel,
            editing: false
        }
        this.props.dispatch({type:"ADD_TODO", todoData })
        this.getTodoTitle.value = "";
        this.getDescription.value = "";
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props, "TODOFORMPROPS")
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getTodoTitle=input} placeholder="Enter Todo" required/>
                    <input type="text" ref={(input)=> this.getDescription=input} placeholder="Enter Description" required/>
                    <PrioritySelector getData={this.handleSubmit} />
                    <button>Add Todo</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



export default connect()(TodoForm);



    // PrioritySelector.js

import React from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class PrioritySelector extends React.Component  {


    componentDidMount() {
        $("#selector").show();
    }

    handleSelect =(e)=> {
       const priorityLevel = this.getPriorityLevel.value;
       this.props.getData(priorityLevel, e)
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="input-field col s12">
                    <select onChange={this.handleSelect} ref={(option)=> this.getPriorityLevel = option} id="selector">
                        <option disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                        <option value="1">Low</option>
                        <option value="2">Medium</option>
                        <option value="3">High</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}


const mapStateToProps=(state)=> {
    return {
        priorityLevel: state
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrioritySelector);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass the event to `getData`.

onChange will give you access to the event, but you still have to pass it to your prop function.
It looks like this :

```
handleSelect = e => {
  const priorityLevel = this.getPriorityLevel.value;
  this.props.getData(e, priorityLevel)
}
```

Your `handleSubmit` function should swap their values around too :

```
handleSubmit=(e, priorityLevel)=> {
```

You see that I switched them around, let me explain why.

`handleSubmit` will be triggered by the add button. This will cause the form to trigger the `handleSubmit` function as well. Therefore that function should have the event parameter first, after that you can add whatever you want.

You should also add `type="submit"` to your button, that will trigger the form action.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I have added the event to the handleselect and made edits to the post. However, now it is not preventing the default action. It is refreshing the page.

Comment: Please look at my changes

Comment: I see. Thanks! The page is not refreshing now but it is submitting the form as soon as I select the priorityLevel. Something new to find out...haha... Thanks brother!

Answer (score 0):

In your child component PrioritySelector you have the click handler handleSelect. handleSelect receives the event object as an argument when clicked. You can simply pass this event to the parents this.props.getData props

```
handleSelect = (event) => {
  const priorityLevel = this.getPriorityLevel.value;
  this.props.getData(priorityLevel, event);
}
```

The parent component's handleSubmit now will have access to the event object that was passed from the child component.

```
handleSubmit = (priorityLevelData, e) => {
  // now has the event object e
  e.preventDefault()
  const todoTitle = this.getTodoTitle.value;
  const description = this.getDescription.value;
  const priorityLevel = priorityLevelData;
  const todoData = {

    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000),
    todoTitle,
    description,
    priorityLevel,
    editing: false
  }
  this.props.dispatch({ type: "ADD_TODO", todoData })
  this.getTodoTitle.value = "";
  this.getDescription.value = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Hi, I have tried this way. Now it is not giving me an error, but it is not preventing the default action. It refreshes the page when the user selects the priority level.